# Selenium fails to initialize

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am running Python 3 on Linux (Ubuntu). Chrome is installed with version 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit). The chromedriver I downloaded matches this version.

However, when trying to start it:

```
urllib3.exceptions.LocationParseError: Failed to parse: http://127.0.0.1:59711/session
```

Starting the chromedriver directly from the terminal does not sprout any errors:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.83 (94abc2237ae0c9a4cb5f035431c8adfb94324633-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#1658}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

If I specify in my python the port, the same error occurs. If I run chromedriver in another terminal instance and initialize it using that port on python, the same issue occurs, and the instance of chromedriver on the other terminal closes.

My Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

webpilot = webdriver.Chrome('/home/slave/Documents/chromedriver')
```

I have tried reinstalling [Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) and checking for updates on my current version (it says no updates are available. Additionally, I have tried directly adding the `chromedriver` to PATH, and installing it from its [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)) package.

Comment: Which version of chrome driver are you using? Which version of Ubuntu? A Docker-based solution could be useful to you?

Comment: Chromedriver 85, same version Chrome. Ubuntu 20. It wouldn't, I've never used Docker and have no idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the complete error log, but upgrading `urllib3` worked for me in this case:

```
pip install -U urllib3
```

And just in case, also do it for `six` and `requests`.